# Print before and after based on column 1 for the given value from 2nd column

Tags: python

Here is what [my CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cyac.png) looks like:

```
1st,2nd ,3rd,4th
10.1.1.1,10.2.2.2,53,dns
10.10.10.1,10.20.20.1,80,http
,10.20.20.2,443,https
,10.20.20.3,80,http
,10.20.20.4,443,https
,10.20.20.5,80,http
10.10.10.2,10.30.30.1,22,ssh
```

I am trying to search for `10.20.20.2` and get the entire section as shown in the picture:

[image: what I am looking for]

But couldn't figure that out.

Here is the code what I have so far:

```
import re
import csv
                
def csv1():
    with open("sample.csv") as search:
        lines = search.readlines()
        m = '10.20.20.2'
        n = '^\d'
        match = False
        
        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if re.search(m, line):
                match = True
                print (line)
                continue
            elif re.match(n, line):
                match = False
                continue
            elif match:
                print (line)
                       
csv1()
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the following code is:

1. You search for the index where your block starts
2. From there you search for the index of the beginning of the next block
3. Now you can just slice the relevant part out of the list

```py
start = -1
end = -1

# Find the beginning index
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('10.20.20.2'):
        start = i
        break

# Find the end index
for i, line in enumerate(lines[start + 1:]):
    if not line.startswith(','):
        end = i + start
        break

# Slice the relevant parts out of your list
result = lines[start:end - 1]
```

Disclaimer: The code is untested.

Comment: modified # Find the end index for i, line in enumerate(lines[start - 1:]): After that end seems to be working- [',10.20.20.2,443,https\n', ',10.20.20.3,80,http\n', ',10.20.20.4,443,https\n', ',10.20.20.5,80,http\n'] but 'Start' is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to achieve this goal.

Step zero, you have to load in memory your dataframe from the csv.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(open('foo.csv'))
```

After this, you can retrieve all the values in the first column that contains your searched value in the second column.

```py
>>> keys = df.ffill()[df['2nd'] == search_value]['1st'].tolist()
>>> keys
['10.10.10.1']
```

And then, with these keys, you can obtain the dataframe (as you wanted) that has in first column the key and in second column, at any place, your searched value.

```py
>>> df[df.ffill()['1st'] == keys[0]]
          1st         2nd  3rd    4th
1  10.10.10.1  10.20.20.1   80   http
2         NaN  10.20.20.2  443  https
3         NaN  10.20.20.3   80   http
4         NaN  10.20.20.4  443  https
5         NaN  10.20.20.5   80   http
```

Note: you can cycle over the keys if you have more than one "section" containing your searched value, or just take the first element if you're confident there are no repetitions.

Answer (score -1):

if i understand well your request you're looking for something like :

```
for line in lines:
   if m in line.split(","):
       match = True
       print (line)
       continue
```

**EDIT:** (since you modified your question and downvoted my answer too)

Once you find a match with the function above, you can either proceed with the key value like the answer above mine, or else you can think about processing the last number of your value, let me explain :

1. You're looking for 10.0.0.2 and you find the line where your match is true
2. You can get the "10.0.0" par by: `line.split(",")[1].split(".")[:-1].join(".")`
3. Now knowing your ip adresses codification, you can get all lines containing values from your subnets **10.0.0.0+1** to your last subnet or eventually your mask.

This is not a generic solution, but it may solve your problem.

Comment: My code above allows me to print from 10.0.0.2 to end line. But I am also looking for backward. Once it matches line for 10.0.0.2 it should look back until it finds the line that starts with a digit and starts printing from that start line to the end line, like it show in the display above.